# grid, on click hide html content of other div

Tags: jquery, class, grid, hover, addclass

I'm having a grid which displays some information on hover.

On click, I get my list content which appears, and it fades out the other div.

The problem I'm having is on click of one of my list, the hover appears in all the other list items... none of those hover informations should appear.

Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
$('ul.thumbs li').on('click', function(){
    $('ul.thumbs li').find('.description').css('opacity',0);
    $('ul.thumbs li').not(this).find('.description').css('opacity',1);
});
```

To understand better, please find my codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxBmYa

You will see that on click of one thumbnail, the hover effect stays on the other.

If anybody has any solutions, it will be awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the way you are using the `not` selector. Please refer to the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/not/). For your use case you can replace the first three lines with the following:

```
$('ul.thumbs li').on('click', function(e){
   $('ul.thumbs li').find('.description').css('opacity',0);
   $(e.target).css('opacity',1);
});
```

In this case `e` is the click event that is being passed as a parameter and `e.target` gives the target element on which the event was registered.

The working pen is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxBmYa)

Comment: thank you for that :) it's awesome :)

last thing I having some headache, is when I click on a thumbnail, I have my content being display. All good now. But If i close the content via the closing button, the hover stop to work . . .do you have any idea why by any chance ? Thank you for all your time !!! you're a star

Comment: In that case that should be another question. :P Please accept the answer if it solved your question and/or upvote it. Also i cant seem to find the code where your mouseover or hover effect is. It makes a lot of sense to treat this as a separate question.